# How can I create multiple chatrooms using the Drupalchat module?

Tags: 7

I want to create multiple chat rooms in [DrupalChat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module.

Anyone can help me to complete this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty similar to the (still active) issue about [Multiple public chat rooms - role controlled](https://www.drupal.org/node/1786326), here is a partial quote from that issue:

> Any chance you can allow the administrator to create more global chat rooms? I would like to create a chat room for Children so Adults cannot gain access and adult rooms where teens and children cannot access.

[Comment nr 4](https://www.drupal.org/node/1786326#comment-6735240) (from the module owner of the [DrupalChat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module) states the following: **this option only exists in "iFlyChat Servers" polling method**.

Here are some more details about iFlyChat (= quote from https://iflychat.com/):

> With iFlyChat, websites need not worry about setting chat server of their own. iFlyChat server will take care of the hosting part and will provide a hassle free setup of chat system. We use latest onCloud technology which gives a faster chatting experience to all users of your website.